# api controller return value Object object while in postman api give perfect otuput

Tags: angular, api

This is my UserApiController ..

```
namespace ShoppingCart.Controllers
{
    public class UserApiController : BaseApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Login(string username, string password)
        {
            return ToJson(db.usp_validateUser(username, password));
        }
    }
}
```

This is BaseApiController ....

```
namespace ShoppingCart.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/UserApi")]
    public class BaseApiController : ApiController
    {
        protected readonly aarshpatelEntities db = new aarshpatelEntities();
        protected HttpResponseMessage ToJson(dynamic obj)
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my service in angular 2 ...

```
return this._http.post(apiUrl, model)
            .map((res: Response) => {

                let user = res.json();

                if (user) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('username', user['UserName']);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Username / Password is incorrect !!");
                }
            })
```

What is wrong with the code ?? I cant figure it out.

Comment: try `let user = res.json().data;` Or try to `console.log(user)` , and see how it looks like.

Comment: Not working both !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.it depend on wich version of Angular are you using ..

If you're using `HTTPCLIENT` ..try:

```
return this._http.post<YOURTYPE || any>(apiUrl, model)
            .map((res: Response) => {

                let user = res;

                if (user) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('username', user['UserName']);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Username / Password is incorrect !!");
                }
            })
```

IF you're using `Http` Provider:

```
return this._http.post<YOURTYPE || any>(apiUrl, model)
                .map((res: Response) => {

                    let user = JSON.Parse(res.json()) 

                    if (user) {
                        sessionStorage.setItem('username', user['UserName']);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Username / Password is incorrect !!");
                    }
                })
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I am using Http And I did as you say but getting undefined in console @federico .

Comment: what if you only do  let user = res.json() as any

Comment: Get object with data but not getting Username in session storage

Comment: you need ro do a JSON.Parse()

Comment: JSON.Serialize() .. ?? :-)

Comment: No ... but it is solved by user[0].UserName
Any way thanks for help !

Comment: mmm so the api is returning a Array and not an object!!